# jQuery scrollLeft not working on horizontal div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The `scrollTo` property of this horizontal div isn't scrolling. This is my jQuery (I've made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/394o7tuy/)

```
$(function() { 
  $('.scroll-row-group').each(function () { 
    var innerContent = $(this).find('div');
    $(this).scrollLeft( (innerContent.width() - $(this).width()) / 2);       
  });
});
```

my css is this

```
.scroll-row-group > .row {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.scroll-row-group > .row > .col-2 {
  display: inline-block;
} 

/* Decorations */
.col-2 { padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; }

.col-2 > abbr{
   font-size: 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
    top: -30px;
 }
```

and the markup is this

```
 <div class="container scroll-row-group">
    <div class="row text-center">
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Nov,<br>2019</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Dec,<br>2019</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><hr style="transform: rotate(90deg); width: 50px; border-color: goldenrod;"><abbr>Jan,<br>2020</abbr><span style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white;">2020-01</span></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Feb,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Mar,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Apr,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>May,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Jun,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Jul,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Aug,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Sep,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Oct,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><hr style="transform: rotate(90deg); width: 50px; border-color: red;"><abbr>Nov,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Dec,<br>2020</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><hr style="transform: rotate(90deg); width: 50px; border-color: goldenrod;"><abbr>Jan,<br>2021</abbr><span style="background-color: blue; color: white;">2021-01</span></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Feb,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Mar,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Apr,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>May,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Jun,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Jul,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Aug,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Sep,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Oct,<br>2021</abbr></div>
       <div class="col-2"><abbr>Nov,<br>2021</abbr></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The idea is that the user will see this horizontal display "`scrollTo`" todays date (in the middle of the +/- year grid, which is marked by the red vertical `<hr>`) can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do? But `(innerContent.width() - $(this).width()) / 2` _seems_ to be `0`.

Comment: @Gabriel, no that's not it - just changing it to "50" does nothing